# Looping a get function with random string

Tags: java, for-loop

```
{
    Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        System.out.printf("%s%n", sentence.getSentence());
}
```

Hey friends, I am stuck. I have created a Class that generates a string that randomizes each word from an array. For some reason when I create the test and create the loop, it will just loop the same randomly generate sentence. My professor asked us to use a for loop to generate each new sentence. How do I get the loop to call a freshly randomized sentence each time, rather than repeating the same one 20 times. The random get function does work, as each time I run it, it will use a new sentence.

Here is the sentence class, I have tested and it seems to run fine on its own or when it is called by test simply once.

```
public class Sentence {
        Word article = new Word();
        Word noun = new Word();
        Word verb = new Word();
        Word preposition = new Word();

        StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder(article.getArticle());
        String capital = Character.toString(buffer1.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
        String buffer2 = capital + buffer1.substring(1,buffer1.length());
        StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder().append(buffer2).append(" ").append(noun.getNoun()).append(" ").append(verb.getVerb()).append(" ").append(preposition.getPreposition()).append(" ").append(article.getArticle()).append(" ").append(noun.getNoun()).append(".");

        public void setSentence (StringBuilder sentence)
        {
            this.sentence = sentence;
        }
        public StringBuilder getSentence()
        {
            return sentence;
        }

}
```

Comment: You repeatedly call getSentence().  What does getSentence do?  We can't tell you because you have not posted its code.  The issue is certainly in the Sentence class, not this loop. Maybe you actually generate the sentence in the constructor (which is only called once).

Comment: It depends on `getSentence()` implementation if you want to generate random numbers you can use `(int) Math.random() * (j + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to reset your code because it does not work as you would like and in addition it is not very functional.

So, I wrote you this piece of code where I set up a constructor useful to automatically create a "sentence" every time you create a `Sentence` object.
Once this is done the after is automatic, just create a `Sentence` object as I've done in the main function and call the `getSentence()` method.
By doing so you take the "sentence" of that particular object you created.

**CODE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            System.out.printf("%s%n", new Sentence().getSentence());
}
```

```
public class Sentence {
    Word article = new Word();
    Word noun = new Word();
    Word verb = new Word();
    Word preposition = new Word();

    StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder(article.getArticle());
    String capital = Character.toString(buffer1.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
    String buffer2 = capital + buffer1.substring(1, buffer1.length());
    StringBuilder sentence;

    public Sentence() {
        sentence = new StringBuilder().append(buffer2).append(" ").append(noun.getNoun()).append(" ").append(verb.getVerb()).append(" ").append(preposition.getPreposition()).append(" ").append(article.getArticle()).append(" ").append(noun.getNoun()).append(".");
    }

    public void setSentence(StringBuilder sentence) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
    }

    public StringBuilder getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I actually put it within the getSentence constructor but it worked the exact same way. Thanks so much!